# How to do name filter for adb logcat?

Tags: android, cmd, android-logcat

I am debugging an apk on phone using cmd. Here are my steps:

- adb install -r D:\apk_path
- adb logcat

Now I am confused with a whole bunch of log. There I did find:

```
I/My Kingdom:(28862): Base Age: 33
```

How to filter all the log with "My Kingdom" name? If possible, please include an option for I/, D/,... too.

Answer (score 0):

use -

```
adb logcat -s "your tag"
```

[logcat help](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

multiple filters-

```
adb logcat -s "tag1","tag2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly just use grep:

```
adb logcat | grep -i "my kingdom"
```

Comment: in case of windows, we need to have `grep.exe`.  Or you should specify grep inside adb shell. `adb shell logcat | grep "whatever"`